# A little question about a group action.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I'm having a little perplexity about the followoing fact explained in [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/ravanbakhsh17a/ravanbakhsh17a.pdf) (Example 1.1):

Consider the group $G :=\mathbb{Z}_6$ and define its action on $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ by defining it on the index set $N=\{1,2,3\}$ as $g \cdot n := g+n \, \, \pmod{3}\, \, \, \, \forall g \in \mathbb{Z}_6$. Is this a well-defined action on $\textbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$?

Let's take $g=1$, and let it act on $N$. Then we would have

$$\textbf{x}=(x_{g\cdot1}, x_{g \cdot 2}, x_{g \cdot 3}) = (x_2, x_0,x_1)$$

What should $x_0$ correspond to here?

Is this just a notational issue or is it a-priori wrong to consider $\pmod{3}$ addition on $\mathbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: Why would it be "a priori wrong"?

Comment: I don't know I'm just used to consider the groups $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +_{modn})$ so the set of integers $mod \, n$ with the respective operation..

Comment: Isn't it just a permutation of the coordinates? I mean, being isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$..

Comment: One would need $g+n\pmod 3\in N$ to start with. I am not sure, for example, what is $0+3\pmod 3$ for $0\in\mathbb Z_6$ and $3\in N$. This can be clarified, e.g. by allowing that $0\pmod 3$ means $3\in N$ rather than $0\not\in N$, or by some other means, but I agree that, definitely, *some* clarification is needed.

Comment: (Cont'd) If by $g+n\pmod 3$ we mean "pull back $g=\gamma/_{\equiv 6}$ to $\gamma\in\mathbb Z$ - i.e. find the whole number $\gamma$ which has a $\pmod 6$ equivalence class $g$; *then* add $\gamma +n$, and take as a result *the unique number $r\in N$ such that $\gamma+n\equiv r\pmod 3$* - then this will work, and this will be a group action ... and there is still work for you to prove that the above definition is correct, i.e. that $r$ is independent of the choice of $\gamma$.

Comment: @JamesArten My guess is that my last comment is correct in what they *mean* by their notation. Please add this link *into the body of your question*, so that the question will be self-contained.

Comment: could you explain a bit better what do you mean by pull-back g to $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you know what they intended to say, ie. the group acts by permuting the coordinates. Strictly speaking, their notation is wrong (or at the very least pretty confusing).

Quick fix: set $N = \{0, 1, 2\}$, and define the action in the same way, where we view $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ as $x = (x_0, x_1, x_2)$. This will result in the 'same' action without the notational errors you noticed.

Comment: That’s exactly what I’ve been doing at first shot! Even though I was not sure about it. And I agree, very bad notation in the paper. Many thanks Jonan!